# Ignoring some of the caption content in listoffigures

Tags: table-of-contents, front-matter

When having a figure caption, I both write a title for the figure and a description of the content. An example could be:

```
\caption{Histogram equalization on Fig0316(2)(2nd\_from\_top).tif.
   {\bf (a)} Original image.
   {\bf (b)} Profile of the original image.
   {\bf (c)} Profile of the resulting image.
   {\bf (d)} Resulting image.
 \label{fig:eq:0316b}
}
```

Now, when I render the `\listoffigures` it includes everything stated within the `\caption{` and `}`. In this case, I only seek to include `Histogram equalization on Fig0316(2)(2nd\_from\_top).tif.` in the `lof`.

How can I obtain that?

Comment: Did you try `\caption[short caption]{long long long caption?}`?

Comment: I have now. Thanks a lot - it did the job :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: do it this way:

```
\begin{figure}
\caption[Histogram equalization on Fig0316(2)(2nd\_from\_top).tif]
{Histogram equalization on Fig0316(2)(2nd\_from\_top).tif.
   {\bf (a)} Original image.
   {\bf (b)} Profile of the original image.
   {\bf (c)} Profile of the resulting image.
   {\bf (d)} Resulting image.
}
 \label{fig:eq:0316b}
\end{figure}
```

You might be interested in using the [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package to typeset the subcaption labels automatically.  Then you don't need a short caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Lorem Ipsum}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for dummy images
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\listoffigures

\section{Lorem Ipsum}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering%
        \includegraphics[width=0.618\linewidth]{example-image-a}
        \subcaption{Original image}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering%
        \includegraphics[width=0.618\textwidth]{example-image-b}
        \subcaption{Profile of the original image}
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering%
        \includegraphics[width=0.618\linewidth]{example-image-c}
        \subcaption{Profile of the resulting image}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering%
        \includegraphics[width=0.618\textwidth,angle=180]{example-image-a}
        \subcaption{Resulting image}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Histogram equalization on Fig0316(2)(2nd\_from\_top).tif}
\end{figure}

\section{Dolor sit amet}

\lipsum[2-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]